# Python program works in IDLE, but not in command line (PowerShell)

Tags: python, powershell

I'm currently trying to write a function that will ask for a number, and the return whether it is prime or not. I plan on getting input using the raw_input() function. This program works if I type it in Python and run it, but when I run it in PowerShell I receive the following error:

```
>>> python ex19.1.py
What is your number? 34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex19.1.py", line 13, in <module>
    is_prime(number)
  File "ex19.1.py", line 5, in is_prime
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I'm currently running Python 2.7, and I'm not sure why I'm receiving a string error as I don't use any string formatters in my code. Below is the code I am using for my program, entitled ex19.1.py.

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
    return True

number = raw_input("What is your number? ")
is_prime(number)
```

My question is, why is this error coming up and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number` should be an **integer** as you commit arithmetic actions using it. However, what you get using `raw_input` is a **string**.

Just convert it to `int`:

```
number = int(raw_input("What is your number? "))
```

---

- The modulo operation for strings is used for string formatting, along with  format string and format arguments. `n % 2` tries to format the string "34" with the integer `2` (when no arguments are required by the format string "34"). That's the reason for this specific error message.

Answer (score 2):

When you take an input from `raw_input`, by default it is a string.

Something like this:

```
>>> n = "2"
>>> n % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

To fix your issue, cast `n` to int and then your code will work fine.

like this:

```
try:
    num = int(number)
    is_prime(num)
except ValueError as e:
    #Some typechecking for integer if you do not like try..except
    print ("Please enter an integer")
```